# Write an If statement to Insert certain data into SQL

Tags: sql, database, powershell, if-statement, inject

Okay this code works perfect it pulls everything from an API the data i need. But i need it to just insert specific data. How do i go in making an IF statement that just inserts data that is named provisioned in Tags and inserts it into SQL. I am very new to powershell so i do not know how to make this work. If someone can guide me in the right direction.

## For loop giving variables to the objects

```
foreach($obj in $Json.devices)

{
    $DeviceIdentifier = $obj.deviceId
    $DeviceNombre = $obj.deviceName
    $DomainNombre = $obj.domainName
    $Tags =$obj.tags


    Write-Host ($obj.deviceId) -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor darkblue
    Write-Host ($obj.devicename) -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor red
    Write-Host ($obj.domainname) -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor red
    Write-Host ($obj.tags) -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor black
```

## Inserting into MYSQL database

```
        $cmd = $connection.CreateCommand()
        $insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tags]([DeviceID],[DeviceName],[DomainName],[Tags])
                            VALUES ('$DeviceIdentifier','$DeviceNombre', '$DomainNombre','$tags')" -replace "\s+"," "
        $cmd.CommandText = $insert_stmt
        write-host $insert_stmt -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor DarkBlue
        $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
}

$Connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter `$Json.devices` down to just objects where `Tags` = `provisioned`.

```
$objs = $Json.devices | Where-Object {$_.tags -eq "provisioned"}
foreach($obj in $objs)
```

Otherwise you could use an `if` statement

```
if ($Tags -eq "provisioned) {
    #Do logic here
}
```

Comment: will the where-obj go after my for each statement or within my for each?

Comment: With `Where-Object` you would filter the object before you looped over it. Only running on the elements that remain. With the `if` you would put it inside the loop and evaluate the conditional for each element you looped over.